# Function returning TABLE and the JOIN in SELECT query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create a local FUNCTION which returns result as NESTED TABLE in my PROCEDURE. Then, I wish to JOIN the nested table with another table in a SELECT query like this:

```
PROCEDURE TEST_DEPID (SOR IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS
 TYPE TAB IS TABLE OF HR.EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE
          INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
FUNCTION GET_SALARY (P_DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER)
   RETURN TAB                                         
   IS   RETURN_TBL   TAB;
   BEGIN
    SELECT  SALARY
       BULK COLLECT INTO RETURN_TBL
       FROM HR.EMPLOYEES WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = TRIM(P_DEPARTMENT_ID);

   RETURN RETURN_TBL;
   END GET_SALARY;

 BEGIN
 OPEN SOR FOR
 SELECT * FROM HR.EMPLOYEES JOIN TABLE (GET_SALARY('60')) B ON A.SALARY = B.SALARY;
 END;
```

And the errors I got are:

```
[1]:(Error): PLS-00231: function 'GET_SALARY' may not be used in SQL
[2]:(Error): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
[3]:(Error): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Please give me some advice.

Comment: can Procedures return value?

Comment: @Bulat: No, it returns errors right after Ctrl + S to save

Comment: it was a general question. Can PL/SQL procedure return values as function?

Comment: No, it cannot. But if I use the function (not local), it works. The matter is I just want to use local function for this procedure.

Comment: I think you need to update the question with working solution and explain how you want to change it

Comment: It will not work with local function. Oracle uses 2 engines running SQL and PL/SQL. Running your SELECT the SQL engine can access all functions, but only if they are public known. The local function is not known to the public.

Comment: Okay, I'm doing that. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: @Christian13467 You should add that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

A local function cannot be used inside a SELECT. Only global functions will work.

Oracle uses 2 engines running SQL and PL/SQL. Running your SELECT the SQL engine can access all functions, but only if they are public known. The local function is not known to the public.